# How to distribute ios app after building with sksl in Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Following the instructions on [sksl warmup](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/shader) running `flutter build ios --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json` produces a `Runner.app`.

I don't understand how to create an archive or an ipa using that build.

How can i distribute a release build with sksl cache?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @SardorbekR nope

Comment: after generating ipa you should use "Transporter" app on macOS to upload it to Testflight/AppStore

Answer (score 6):

Use the below command to create ios archive with shaders cache, which you can distribute on app store. [visit here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive) for more info on flutter official documentation

```
flutter build ipa --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json
```

Comment: How that ipa can be installed in a device? Does it needs to be published directly to the store or is some xcode command that can be run?